# Using node+express with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ejs

For instance, I have index.ejs

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/banana", {
        template : 
    })
    .when("/tomato", {
        template :
    });
});
```

Question here is how to render banana.ejs and tomato.ejs like SPA? So, when I click on the "banana" it should render banana.ejs(not banana.html) without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may use this following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/!">Main</a></p>

<a href="#!red">Red</a>
<a href="#!green">Green</a>
<a href="#!blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script>

<p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no! Sorry, but it won't work because my website is dynamic not static, I have authorization(sign up and sign in) system which is way it wont' work if I use .html instead of .ejs